# How to create an array with ajax and modify it without callback function?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, recursion, spotify

I'm trying to use callbacks to get rid of the synchronous ajax calls in my code but I can't figure out how this could work. I'm using the spotify API to get all the artists in a playlist then perform tasks based on that information. The basic logic of the code is:

1. Get the user's playlist selections
2. Populate an array with the artist ids in those playlists
3. Make more ajax calls based on the array.
4. Use the array from step 3 to do another task.

The problem is that step 4 will come before step 2 and 3 if I don't set step 2 and 3 to synchronous. BUT I can't just call step three at the end of the step 2, and step 4 at the end of step 3 function because both occur in a while loop. Can't figure out a solution to this.

**The calling function**

This while loop goes through all a user's selections in a multiple selection box and calls the ajax function to append the data.

```
artistArray = [];

while (artistUrls[i] != null) {
    getArtists(artistArray, artistUrls[i]);
    i++;
}

doSomethingWithArtistArray(artistArray);

doAnotherThingWithArray(artistsArray);
```

**The ajax function**

Uses ajax calls to get the artist information and append it to an array

```
getArtists(artistArray, url) {
    (if (url == null) {
        return;
    }

    $.ajax({
              async: false,
              url: url,
              headers: {
                'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + access_token
              },
              error: function() {
                console.log("Something went wrong with " + url);
                return;
              },

              success: function(tracks) {
                getArtists_Append(artists, frequencyArray, tracks); //Uses a while loop to append all the artist information to artistArray
              },

            });
            //My idea was to call doSomethingWithArtistArray here but that's not working because there might be more calls to make.
            console.log("finished getting artists");
            return;
          }
}
```

**Get artists=**

```
getArtists_Append {

while loop that populates the array
}
```

Comment: Can't you just call `doSomethingWithArtistArray` in the `success` function of the `getArtists` ajax function ? Then call `doAnotherThingWithArray` in the `success` function of the `doSomethingWithArtistArray` ajax function?

Comment: What you probably need is to use `promise`'s - or in jQueery speak, `$.Deferred`

Comment: it should work.. as you are using `async:false`... but it is not  a good solution to use... especially in a loop.... is there a particular reason to do so

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/x2z758q7/1/ - there is some syntax errors in your function

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that you are treating your Ajax requests as if they were synchronous, when they are asynchronous (and you should do it like that to prevent blocking the browser).

The best approach is to:

1. In the specific case of fetching multiple artists from Spotify, use the endpoint for [getting several artists](https://developer.spotify.com/web-api/get-several-artists/). This will reduce the amount of requests you need to make to the Spotify's Web API.
2. If using callback functions, you will make an Ajax request. Then in its callback you will check if you need to make another Ajax request with the next chunk. If you don't need to make any other request because you are done, then call your next function, in this case `doSomethingWithArtistArray`.
3. If you are using Promises, then use `Promise.all()` passing an array of promises, where each promise wraps an Ajax request. This is useful when you already know what requests you need to make, and don't need the response from a request to figure out the next request to be made.

Have a look at the [Code Examples section](https://developer.spotify.com/web-api/code-examples/) on the Spotify Developer Site to see some open source sites using the Web API.

For instance, you can see how the 2nd alternative is applied in [Sort Your Music](http://static.echonest.com/SortYourMusic/) when [getting playlists tracks](https://github.com/plamere/SortYourMusic/blob/eb0822a58a6383af59537c6fef351e21246f8a53/web/index.html#L454). The function will make a request to the next chunk if there are more tracks to fetch, otherwise it won't.

For the 3rd alternative, since you are using jQuery you could use `$.when` to use promises. Check out [this example](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.when/#entry-examples). If you like the idea of promises and plan to make other requests to the Web API, I would recommend you using a wrapper like [Spotify Web API JS](https://github.com/JMPerez/spotify-web-api-js) (shameless self promotion). With that you could simply do:

```
var api = new SpotifyWebApi();

var promises = [];
promises.add(api.getArtists(['id1', 'id2', 'id3', 'id4', 'id5']));
promises.add(api.getArtists(['id10', 'id11', 'id12', 'id13', 'id14']));
Promise.all(promises).then(function(data) {
  // data contains the result of the promises (ajax requests)
  // do something with it
});
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply (even though my response is quite late)! I used promises to get it working and I'm pretty happy with the result. My only issue is that some of the responses for an artist's related artists are coming back undefined. Will figure that on my own.

Comment: Check if those artists have related artists in their Spotify pages on the Spotify application. If there are, they should be returned. You can also check a request easily using the Web API Console https://developer.spotify.com/web-api/console/get-artist-related-artists/